# How to make vbscript run as local administrator

Tags: printing, vbscript, administrator, runas

I'm very new to VBscript I'm at work under a domain. I want to be able to install printers on every users machine by having them run this script. But the users don't have the credentials to  run script.

Is there a way for me to add log in credentials in the VBscript

```
set objNetwork = Createobject("WScript.Network")
'objNetwork.AddwindowsPrinterConnection "\\print-serv\HP LaserJet 4350 PCL 5 it"
objNetwork.AddwindowsPrinterConnection "\\print-serv\uniFlow Secure Print"
'objNetwork.AddwindowsPrinterConnection "\\print-serv\Brother HL-4570CDW color"
wscript.echo "Printers have been Mapped
```

Comment: Can't you use GPO to deploy?

Comment: No i don't have access to the group policy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PSExec to execute your script remotely.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

You'll be able to pass the computer name, or a list of computers in a text file, and the credentials you'd like to run your script as. Something like this:

```
psexec \\computer1 -u admin -p password c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe \\computer2\share\yourscript.vbs
```

Comment: +1 - where would the world of remote administration be without Mark Russinovich?

Comment: The guy is a genius. I have no idea how he even figured out half of this stuff in the first place.

Comment: But what if i don't know every computer name in the Department over 500+ Computer names ?

Comment: Retrieve it from AD. https://www.google.com/search?q=get+all+computer+names+in+ou

Comment: Note that you'll need to run it in batches of a couple dozen hosts.